# ¿Cómo obtener valor de select option php en ciclo for?

Tags: php, html

hola que tal necesito obtener el valor seleccionado por el usuario en el option, lo tengo dentro de un ciclo for porque tengo diferentes cantidades, estas cantidades viene desde el stock en mi base de datos, lo que quiero es poder sacar solamente el valor seleccionado por el usuario, y guardarlo en una variable, el codigo es el siguiente. muchas gracias

```
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                <label class="product-text mr-sm-2" for="formCantidad">Cantidad:</label>
                <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" name="cantidadd" id="cantidadd">
                  <?php
                    for($i = 1; $i <= $producto['unitsinstock']; $i++){
                  ?>
                  <option value='<?php $i ?>'  ><?php echo $i ?></option>
                  <?php
                  // $seleccionado=$producto[$i];
                  $quantity= $_POST['cantidadd'];
                    }
                  ?>
                </select>
              
              
              <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['productid'],COD,KEY);?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="picture" id="picture" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['picture'],COD,KEY);?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['productname'],COD,KEY); ?>" >
              <input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['price'],COD,KEY); ?>" >
              <input type="hidden" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($quantity,COD,KEY); ?>" >
              <?php
                if($producto['unitsinstock'] >0) {
              ?>
              <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block my-4" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit" >Agregar al carrito</button>
              <?php
                } else {
              ?>
              <a  href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-block disabled my-4">Agotado</a>
              <?php
                }
              ?>
            </form>
```

Comment: Debes quitar el selected que estas agregando a cada option, cuando selecciones un valor y lo envies via POST, simplemente obten el valor del $_POST['cantidad'], PD: por favor no escribas todo en mayuscula parece como que gritas.

Comment: Que tal amigo no me funciona, mira el código lo tengo así.

Comment: Listo amigo ya lo hice, puedes ayudarme con mi pregunta?

Comment: NO GRITES POR FAVOR

Comment: Las etiquetas inline de PHP deberían ser así: `<?= $i; ?>`. Luego, para obtener el valor seleccionado por el usuario, usaría `$_POST['cantidadd'];` (si, hay dos 'd').

Comment: Y claramente, el atributo `action` de `<form>` debe contener un destino que procese el formulario...

Answer (score -1):

el mejor metodo para seleccionar un option ya definido es utilizar jquey, la otra forma es utilizar javasript, colocando una condicion de la cantidad maxima

```js
$( "#cantidad" ).change(function() {
var cantidad =$('#cantidad').val();
 var maxima_cantida=3;  
  
  if(cantidad>maxima_cantida){
  alert( "la cantidad."+cantidad );
  $('#cantidad').val(maxima_cantida);
  }
  
  //$('#cantidad').val(3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
              <?php
                for($i = 1; $i <= $producto['unitsinstock']; $i++){
              ?>
              <option value='<?php $i ?>' selected ><?php echo $i ?></option>
              <?php
              // $seleccionado=$producto[$i];
                }
              ?>
              <option value='1' selected >1</option>
              <option value='2' selected >2</option>
              <option value='3' selected >3</option>
              <option value='4' selected >4</option>
              <option value='5' selected >5</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Me puedes decir como sacarlo con el if, no importa que se vea mal, lo único que necesito es obtener el valor seleccionado, y guardarlo en una variable, ya intente con jquery, ajax, y no me funciono, podrias decirme como con el if, que mencionas